# Using Akka with Eclipse (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, sbt, akka, typesafe

I am able to include the required jar files and run my Akka code. But I want to generate the correct folder structure for using Akka using eclipse. I am not able to understand how should I go about it. Should I install SBT first, then some eclipse plugin. How can I run akka microkernal for my Akka Java code. Step by step of what do to in order to achieve that would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Akka is just a library, you add the jars it needs just like any other library. But it does depend on other libraries such as the scala library, easiest way is to use maven, with the maven eclipse plugin this is:

File -> New -> Maven Project -> (select Create Simple Project) -> (add txt for Grup ID and Artifact Id: eg junk )

Then edit the pom so it looks like this

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    junk
    junk
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4-M2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Then maven gets all the libraries you need, otherwise
you'll need to add the following jars to the classpath manually:

akka-actor_2.11-2.4-M2.jar

scala-library-2.11.6.jar

config-1.3.0.jar

Note that this is for java though sorry, do this for scala it is very similar, just change the pom to be http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/akka-2.3/akka-samples/akka-sample-main-java-lambda/pom.xml.shtml and make sure you add scala nature to the project if you need to when you try and create scala files in it